# Not able to use HTML variables in JavaScript when used prints whole JavaScript code in the browser

Tags: javascript, html

This is the registration form in which I'm not able to access JavaScript variable from html form, instead it prints whole JavaScript code in the browser. I am not including CSS files here as it is correct please me with these code.

HTML code

```
<form action = "book.js" name = "myform" onsubmit="return hello();">
<label for = "f_name" class = "ft"> First Name: </label>
<input  type = "textbox" name = "f_name" class = "desi" placeholder = "f_name">
<br><br>
<label for = "l_name" class = "ft"> Last Name: </label>
<input type = "textbox" name = "l_name" class = "desi" placeholder = "l_name">
<br><br>
<label for = "er_no" class = "ft"> Enrollment Number: </label>
<input type = "textbox" name = "er_no" class = "desi" placeholder = "10characters">
<br><br>
<label for = "sem" class = "ft"> Semester: </label>
<input type = "textbox" name = "sem" class = "desi"  placeholder = "less than eight">
<br><br>
<label for = "c_p"class = "ft"> Create Password: </label>
<input type = "password" name = "c_p" class = "desi" placeholder = "8 alphanumeric">
<br><br>
<label for = "e_p" class = "ft"> Enter Password: </label>
<input type = "password" name = "e_p" class = "desi" placeholder = "8 alphanumeric">
<br><br>
<input type = "submit" style = "background-color:yellow;color:red">
</form>
```

JavaScript code

When I run in the browser whole JavaScript code is printed which is shown 
below.

```
    function hello()
    {

        var f_names = document.myform.f_name.value;
        var l_names = document.myform.l_name.value;
        var er_nos = document.myform.er_no.value;
        var sems = document.myform.sem.value;
        var c_ps = document.myform.c_p.value;
        var e_ps = document.myform.e_p.value;
        for(var i=0;i<er_no.length;i++)
        {
            if(!(er_no[i]>=0 && er[i]<=9))
            {
                alert("wrong enrollment number");
                return(false);
            }
        }
        if(sems>'8')
        {
            alert("invalid semester");
            return(false);
        }
    document.write("hello");
    return(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute, and not display, your JavaScript code, you need to encapsulate your JavaScript code in a `<script>` tag as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// your code
</script>
```